# i3wm open 2 applications with one keybinding?

Tags: i3-wm

I want to make a keybinding for i3wm that launches 2 GUI applications at the same  time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can chain i3 commands by passing a list, which is separated by either `,` or `;`. For example, this will open a terminal and `xclock` on pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>:

```
bindkey Mod4+x exec i3-sensible-terminal; exec xclock
```

**Note:** while `exec i3-sensible-terminal` will be run before `exec xclock`, there is no guarantee that the window for `i3-sensible-terminal` will open before the window of `xclock`. That is due to the fact that `exec` does not wait for a window to be mapped before returning. (In fact it can not wait, as there is no way to know, if an application is even going to open a window.)

---

For more information about command chaining have a look at the [i3 User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_chaining)

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use the bash built in && chaining but that only launched the second application after I closed the first one.